# MYSQL running query in command to update table data showing bash error

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell

I have a mysql query to update the a table(index) data using column names from another table(index_tmp), here is the query

```
INSERT INTO index(
    `CIN`, `companyName`, `Charge ID`, `Date of Charge`,
    `Charge amount secured`, `Charg Holder`, `Address`,
    `SRN`, `Created_Date`, `Modified_Date`,
    `Date_Of_Satisfaction`, `Change`)
SELECT `CIN`, `companyName`, `Charge ID`, `Date of Charge`,
       `Charge amount secured`, `Charge Holder`, `Address`,
       `SRN`, `Created_Date`, `Modified_Date`,
       `Date_Of_Satisfaction`, `Change` 
FROM index_tmp where `Change` = "New"
```

This query runs without any error inside mysql, but when I tried to run it from command line I get the below error,

```
$ mysql -uroot -p -e "query"

bash: CIN: command not found
bash: companyName: command not found
bash: Charge: command not found
bash: Date: command not found
bash: Charge: command not found
bash: Charge: command not found
bash: Address: command not found
bash: SRN: command not found
bash: Created_Date: command not found
bash: Modified_Date: command not found
bash: Date_Of_Satisfaction: command not found
bash: Change: command not found
bash: CIN: command not found
bash: companyName: command not found
bash: Charge: command not found
bash: Date: command not found
bash: Charge: command not found
bash: Charge: command not found
bash: Address: command not found
bash: SRN: command not found
bash: Created_Date: command not found
bash: Modified_Date: command not found
bash: Date_Of_Satisfaction: command not found
bash: Change: command not found
bash: Change: command not found
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',,,,,,,,,,) SELECT ,,,,,,,,,,, FROM index_of_charges_tmpd where  = New' at line 1
```

Mysql version 5.6

Comment: Index is a reserved word in mysql if it ran succesfully in mysql you must have backticked it.

Comment: The full name of table is index_charge. I'm trying to run it in CLI like mysql -uroot -p -e "full_query" and getting the error.

Comment: @sam use single quotes instead of double quotes, otherwise backticks are interpolated by the shell as commands.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. In particular, your question does not include a [mcve] and is as such off-topic. Also, review the descriptions of the tags that you applied, half of them are wrong.

Comment: In bash, backticks mean that the text between those is to be executed.  So it tried to run commands CIN, companyName, ...  To run a query in the command line, you should do some research, this has been addresses many times on SO.

Answer (score 0):

We can see from how `bash` is trying to execute your MySQL identifiers wrapped in backticks that you aren't escaping your query to prevent it from being interpreted by your command shell.  Wrap it in single quotes, or perhaps put it in a file and provide it to `mysql` with `<`.